# how to randomize and insert question with picture

Tags: java, image, random, insert

please java code to insert picture and random quiz. it does not work:

```
let MCQS = [
   {question: "What does HTML stand for?",
      choice1: "Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language",
      choice2: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
      choice3: "Hyper Text Making Language",
      choice4: "Hyper Text Mark Language",
      answer: 1
   },
   {question: "What does CSS stand for?",
      choice1: "Colorful StyleSheet",
      choice2: "Creative Style Sheet",
      choice3: "Cascading Style Sheet",
      choice4: "Computer Style Sheet",
      answer: 2
   },
   {question: "Which HTML tag is used to define an internal style sheet?",
      choice1: "<script>",
      choice2: "<style>",
      choice3: "<html>",
      choice4: "<svg>",
      answer: 1
   },
   {question: "Which is the correct CSS syntax?",
      choice1: "body{color:black}",
      choice2: "{body{color:black}",
      choice3: "body={color:black}",  
      choice4: "body:color{black}",
      answer: 0
   },
   {question: "How do you insert a comment in a CSS file?",
      choice1: "/*This is Comment*/",
      choice2: "//This Is Comment",
      choice3: "<!--- This Is Comment --->",
      choice4: "//This Is Comment//",
      answer: 1
   },
   {question: "How do you insert a comment in a HTML file?",
      choice1: "/*This is Comment*/",
      choice2: "//This Is Comment",
      choice3: "<!--- This Is Comment --->",
      choice4: "//This Is Comment//",
      answer: 2
   },
   {question: "Which property is used to change the background color?",
      choice1: "backgroundColor",
      choice2: "BgColor",
      choice3: "Color-Background",
      choice4: "background",
      answer: 3
   },
   {question: "How to write an IF statement in JavaScript?",
      choice1: "if i==5",
      choice2: "if(i==5)",
      choice3: "if(i==5)then",
      choice4: "if i==5 then",
      answer: 2
   },
   {question: "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?",
      choice1: "xxxx",
      choice2: "xxxxxxx",
      choice3: "xxxxxxxxxx",
      choice4: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      answer: 2
   },
   {question: "How does a WHILE loop start?",
      choice1: "while(i <= 0)",
      choice2: "while(i <= 0 i++)",
      choice3: "while i <= 0",
      choice4: "while (i++ i <= 0)",
      answer: 0
   }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the questions are contained within a 2D String Array (`String[][] questions;`). Even though the answers are integer values, keep the array as String anyways just to keep things simple. This data would be better if it were in a file and the Array is filled by reading that file rather than hard coded. This is only done as a quick demo.

Once you have your 2D String[][] Array filled with question data, take each internal String[] Array and add an additional element to the end of **all** of them. This additional element should contain the path and file name to the image you want related to that particular question, for example:

```
{"What does HTML stand for?",
 "Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language",
 "Hyper Text Markup Language",
 "Hyper Text Making Language",
 "Hyper Text Mark Language",
 "1",
 "C:/QuizImages/Quiz_1/WhatIsHTML.png"
},
```

Once this is done and you have all your images contained within the local file system directory specified within that path you placed as the last element for each internal String[] array (remember...in Java, a 2D array is an Array of Arrays), you can now start asking the questions...randomly.

Before you start randomly asking the questions you need to consider ensuring that the  same question won't be asked twice throughout the quiz. Because the questions will be asked randomly, you will need to keep track of which questions were already asked and answered. To do this you can place the asked question number (questions array Index value) within an ArrayList or List of Integer:

```
List<Integer> alreadyAskedQuestions = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, we already know how many questions there are: `questions.length;`, you just need to pull out a random index value from **0** to `questions.length - 1;` using the [java.util.Random.nextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm) method ( - 1 on the length because array indexing starts from **0** not 1). If you use Random like this: `java.util.Random().nextInt(numOfQuestions);` it wont really matter since the value in `numOfQuestions` would be exclusive in the random value generation.

The runnable example code below demonstrates how this can be done as a Condole Application. Notice the image paths supplied within the 2D String Array. You will need to provide the proper paths and file names to your images.

In the runnable below, if the User gets an answer correct then a custom JOptionPane dialog is displayed showing the image related to the Question. When the dialog is closed, the next question is displayed in Console.

Read the Comments in code:

```
public class QuizWithImagesDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuizWithImagesDemo().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        /* 10 Questions in a 2D String Array (String[][]). 
           NOTE: This sort of thing is better read in from 
                 a file rather than hard coded like this. 
                 It is only done this way for Demo.    */
        String[][] questions = {
            {"What does HTML stand for?",
                "Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language",
                "Hyper Text Markup Language",
                "Hyper Text Making Language",
                "Hyper Text Mark Language",
                "1",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image1.jpg"},
            {"What does CSS stand for?",
                "Colorful StyleSheet",
                "Creative Style Sheet",
                "Cascading Style Sheet",
                "Computer Style Sheet",
                "2",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image2.jpg"},
            {"Which HTML tag is used to define an internal style sheet?",
                "<script>",
                "<style>",
                "<html>",
                "<svg>",
                "1",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image3.jpg"},
            {"Which is the correct CSS syntax?",
                "body{color:black}",
                "{body{color:black}",
                "body={color:black}",
                "body:color{black}",
                "0",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image4.jpg"},
            {"How do you insert a comment in a CSS file?",
                "/*This is Comment*/",
                "//This Is Comment",
                "<!--- This Is Comment --->",
                "//This Is Comment//",
                "1",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image5.jpg"},
            {"How do you insert a comment in a HTML file?",
                "/*This is Comment*/",
                "//This Is Comment",
                "<!--- This Is Comment --->",
                "//This Is Comment//",
                "2",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image6.jpg"},
            {"Which property is used to change the background color?",
                "backgroundColor",
                "BgColor",
                "Color-Background",
                "background",
                "3",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image7.jpg"},
            {"How to write an IF statement in JavaScript?",
                "if i==5",
                "if(i==5)",
                "if(i==5)then",
                "if i==5 then",
                "2",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image8.jpg"},
            {"Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?",
                "xxxx",
                "xxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "2",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image9.jpg"},
            {"How does a WHILE loop start?",
                "while(i <= 0)",
                "while(i <= 0 i++)",
                "while i <= 0",
                "while (i++ i <= 0)",
                "0",
                "D:/QuizImages/Quiz_2422/Image10.jpg"}};

        java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfQuestions = questions.length;
        String theQuestion = "Unknown";
        String[] choices = new String[4];
        String answer = "";
        String imagePath = "";
        java.util.List<Integer> alreadyAskedQuestions = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        
        int questCount = 0;
        int score = 0;
        while (questCount != numOfQuestions) {
            /* Get a Random Question Number then check 
               to make sure it hasn't been asked already. 
               If it hasn't then add it to the list.   */
            boolean isUnique = false;
            int rndQuestNum = -1;
            while (!isUnique) {
                rndQuestNum = new java.util.Random().nextInt(numOfQuestions);
                if (!alreadyAskedQuestions.contains(rndQuestNum)) {
                    isUnique = true;
                    alreadyAskedQuestions.add(rndQuestNum);
                }
            }
            
            // Acquire the data from the randomly selected question...
            for (int i = 0; i < questions[rndQuestNum].length; i++) {
                theQuestion = questions[rndQuestNum][0];
                choices[0] = questions[rndQuestNum][1];
                choices[1] = questions[rndQuestNum][2];
                choices[2] = questions[rndQuestNum][3];
                choices[3] = questions[rndQuestNum][4];
                answer = questions[rndQuestNum][5];
                imagePath = questions[rndQuestNum][6];
            }
            
            // Ask the Question and get the answer...
            String ans = "";
            while (ans.isEmpty()) {
                // Print the question to Console Window...
                String title = "Question " + (questCount + 1) + " of " + numOfQuestions + ":";
                System.out.println(title);
                String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(title.length(), "-"));
                System.out.println(underline);
                
                System.out.println(theQuestion);
                for (int c = 0; c < choices.length; c++) {
                    System.out.println("  " + (c + 1) + ") " + choices[c]);
                }
                System.out.print("your Choice? -> ");
                ans = userInput.nextLine().trim();  // Get user input.
                
                // If 'q' was entered then quit.
                if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    return;
                }
                // Validate entry. 0 - 4 can only be supplied!
                if (!ans.matches("[01234]")) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Entry! (" + ans + ") - Try again...");
                    System.out.println();
                    ans = "";
                }
            }
            
            // Is the answer right or wrong?
            if (ans.equals(answer)) {
                System.out.println("CORRECT ANSWER!");
                
                score++;  // add 1 to score if correct.
                
                /* Show the related image to Question if the 
                   answer is correct.  */
                showImageInDialog(imagePath);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("WRONG ANSWER!");
            }
            
            questCount++; // increment question counter.
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    private void showImageInDialog(String imagePath) {
        // Create a parent to dialog can hide behind other applications.
        javax.swing.JDialog parent = new javax.swing.JDialog();
        parent.setTitle("Quiz Question Image");
        parent.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        parent.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        // Creat a custom panel for JOPtionPane
        javax.swing.JPanel jp = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        
        // Set a desired Layout
        jp.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1,1));
        
        // Set the desired size of custom Panel in JOptionPane.
        jp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 300));
        
        // Create a JLabel to place the image in
        javax.swing.JLabel label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        
        // Place a 2 pixel line border around JLabel.
        label.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(java.awt.Color.BLACK, 2));
        // Make sure the JLabel is Opaque
        label.setOpaque(true);
        
        // Add the JLabel to the JPanel.
        jp.add(label);
        
        // Ensure the Image is sized to fit in JLabel
        javax.swing.ImageIcon icon = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(imagePath);
        java.awt.Image img = icon.getImage();
        java.awt.Image resizedImage = img.getScaledInstance(400, 300, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        // Place the resized image into JLabel.
        label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(resizedImage));
        
        // Display the JOptionPane Message Dialog Box.
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, jp, "Related Image", 
                                    javax.swing.JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        parent.dispose();
    }
    
}
```